# C++ override resolution with mixins and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I am puzzled by the behavior below that I am unable to explain. I tried to write a meaningful title but I am not sure I nailed it.

A bit of background, first.
I write numerical simulations software and I am trying to modernize my code a bit. I have three numerical solvers: `primal`, `dual` and `adaptive`.
A `primal` solver does its work unaware of anything else; a `dual` solver has many things in common with a `primal` but is never used alone, and an `adaptive` solver is a wrapper that contains and runs a `primal` and a `dual`, in this order.
Now, the thing is that when an `adaptive` solver runs its `primal` solver, the `primal` needs to perform some additional operations as compared to when it is used alone. Let one such operation be `save`. Also, `primal` and `dual` have a lot in common so I figured they should share code in a `common` class.

This was my initial design

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename s>
struct common
{
    void run()
    {
        static_cast<s*>(this)->save();
    }
};

struct primal : public common<primal>
{
    virtual void save()
    {
        cout << "  Primal\n";
    }
};

struct dual : public common<dual>
{
    void save()
    {
        cout << "  Dual\n";
    }
};

struct adaptive : public primal,
                  public dual
{
    void run()
    {
        primal::run();
        dual::run();
    }

    virtual void save()
    {
        primal::save();
        cout << "    Adaptive\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    adaptive a;
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

and it prints

```
  Primal
    Adaptive
  Dual
```

which, to me, means that

1. `a.run` calls `primal::run = common<primal>::run`
2. `common<primal>::run` calls `primal::save`, but this method is `virtual` so it resolves to calling `adaptive::save`
3. `adaptive::save` calls `primal::save` explicitly, because I want it to perform `primal`'s normal tasks plus something else
4. `adaptive::save` does some other work and returns
5. `a.run` calls `dual::run = common<dual>::run`, which calls `dual::save`, but this method is *not* `virtual` so it is selected ignoring `adaptive::save`.

All is well so far, and this is exactly what I wanted.
So, first question: is all the above correct?

Now, here come the problems.
After some refactoring, `primal::save` and `dual::save` are now the same function, so I want to put it into `common` and keep extending the behavior in `adaptive` only.

As a first step, I changed the code to

```cpp
template <typename s>
struct common
{
    void run()
    {
        save();
    }

    virtual void save()
    {
        cout << "This should never be called\n";
    }
};

// Everything else stays the same
```

and now the output is

```
  Primal
    Adaptive
  Primal
    Adaptive
```

while I was expecting the same output as before.
This is the first thing that I do not understand: it seems to me that now the call to `dual::save` made by `dual::run()` is being resolved all the way to `adaptive::save` while I was expecting it to stop at `dual::save` as this method is not `virtual`.
This is my second question: why is this happening? What is different from before?

Finally, I wrote the code as I had it in mind in its final version, plus some debugging stuff, and it looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename s>
struct common
{
    void run()
    {
        save();
    }

    virtual void save()
    {
        cout << s::name << "::common\n";
    }
};

struct primal : public common<primal>
{
    static const string name;
};
const string primal::name = "primal";

struct dual : public common<dual>
{
    static const string name;
};
const string dual::name = "dual";

struct adaptive : public primal,
                  public dual
{
    virtual void save()
    {
        primal::save();
        cout << "    Adaptive\n";
    }

    void run()
    {
        primal::run();
        dual::run();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    adaptive a;
    a.run();

    return 0;
}
```

and it prints

```
primal::common
    Adaptive
primal::common
    Adaptive
```

as the previous version, while I was expecting

```
primal::common
    Adaptive
dual::common
```

The final question is then on how I can get it to do what I want.

Thanks for reading all the way through here, any hint is appreciated!
I have to stick to C++98 if possible.

Comment: Do you understand _why_ you're getting the output you are?  Use a debugger to step thru the code if necessary.  That's an important step in figuring out how to do what you want to.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with an emphasis on *MINIMAL*.   We don't need a backstory, either.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I do not understand it, and I tried to make it clear that that is in fact the point of the question by repeatedly writing it.

Answer (score 0):

First, an explanation on why you're getting the output you see.

`a.run` calls `adaptive.run`.  `adaptive.run` first explicitly calls `primal::run`, which will call the virtual `save` function, `adaptive::save`.

`adaptive::save` explicitly calls `primal::save` (`common<primal>::save`) and outputs "primal::common".  We then return back into `adaptive::save` and output "Adaptive", then return back to `adaptive::run`.

Now we explicitly call `dual::run` (`common<dual>::run`).  This will call the virtual `save` function, which will again be the `adaptive::save` override which will duplicate your existing output.

**How do you fix it to get what you want?**

That depends on some details that are not present in your question.  Here are some possibilities.

The simplest way would be to explicitly call `dual::save` from within `adaptive::save`, but I presume this won't work for you since `dual` has work to do before that can happen.

You can have `adaptive::save` do nothing, then call `save` for both subobjects within `run`.

You could make `run` `virtual` and override within the `dual` class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! What you describe is what I meant in my post, but still it's not clear to me why the compiler chooses `adaptive::save` for `common<dual>::save` when there is `dual::save` higher in the hierarchy that is not virtual.
Calling `dual::save` from `adaptive::save` is tricky because `run` will do a bunch of stuff and call `save` multiple times before returning, and I have several functions like `save`. I could store a flag in the classes and check it whenever one of these functions is called but it looks ugly. Overriding `run` duplicates code, which I'd like to avoid.